# Change return type of an image .net Core2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have code snippet that has an extended method, I got of a .net core blog with a return type of canvas.

how do I assign the return type to an image and display it on an image label. Here is my code below.

Instead of  return new FileStreamResult(ms, "image/jpg")

I want to do something like this

ViewData["Image"] = new FileStreamResult(ms, "image/jpg")

Then assign it to an image placeholder in my view
thanks

```
                using (Image img = Image.FromStream(pic.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                // ResizeImageASPNETCore.Extends.Resize(img, 50, 50);
                Stream ms = new MemoryStream(img.Resize(500, 500).ToByteArray());
                Stream ms2 = new MemoryStream(img.Resize(50, 50).ToByteArray());

                return new FileStreamResult(ms, "image/jpg");`enter code here`
```

and the extended class is

```
        #endregion

        #region get resized bitmap
        var canvas = new Bitmap(width, height);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(canvas))
        {
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            graphics.DrawImage(current, 0, 0, width, height);
        }

        return canvas;
        #endregion
    }

    public static byte[] ToByteArray(this Image current)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            current.Save(stream, current.RawFormat);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please stop adding incorrect tags to questions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to base64 encode the image and set the src to that.

Check this SO out:  [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)